# setting up docker permission to VSTS agent in a private pipeline

Tags: docker, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have set a private pipeline with linux vm and agent is install and in the portal it shows that the agent is active. I also have install docker. In the same machine if I use sudo docker it works. So I am sure it is a permission issues when the VSTS agent is running the command. Not sure what which user i need to give which premission so that docker command will run when I initial a build from VSTS.

> Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon
>   socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post
>   http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v***.37/build?buildargs=%7B%7D&cachefrom=%5B]&cgroupparent=&cpuperiod=0&cpuquota=0&cpusetcpus=&cpusetmems=&cpushares=0&dockerfile=Dockerfile&labels=%7B%7D&memory=0&memswap=0&networkmode=default&rm=***&session=a53bebddc77c89993b6e464d9f2a56fac9b***e62***094***fe70355df2c8dfcf***8b9&shmsize=0&t=mycontainerreg.azurecr.io%2Ftk-dashboard%3A853&target=&ulimits=null:
>   dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
>
> /usr/bin/docker failed with return code: ***

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In VSTS, it's the build service account which execute entire build pipeline. This account should also run the command.

Note, the service is setting up during the configuration of build agent.  You can run the build agent as a systemd service. More details please refer to this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=vsts#run-as-a-systemd-service).

You will need to grant appropriate permissions. The user  just needs to be added to the group docker.

`sudo usermod -a -G docker user`

Also restart the systemd service and try to trigger the build again.

Comment: I ran ./svc.sh status and got the process id and base on the process id i was able to find the user name "myuser". then I ran sudo usermod -a -G docker myuser. this added "myuser" to the docker group verified by running awk -F':' '/docker/{print $4}' /etc/group. I still get the same issue

Comment: Please note after adding restart of the machine is required

Comment: I ended up running `./env.sh; sudo ./svc.sh stop; sudo ./svc.sh start` and this resolved the problem for me.

Comment: To be clear - you don't need to restart the VM. Just the service (process) running on the agent.

Comment: Running ./env.sh; sudo ./svc.sh stop; sudo ./svc.sh start does not fix the problem for me. Any idea why ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if the docker group was created.
If the gourp does not exist -> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket

Then

`sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`

`sudo usermod -aG root $USER`

`sudo chmod 777 /var/run/docker.sock`

Answer (score 0):

I had to run following commands to get rid off this issue:

```
sudo usermod -aG docker vstsbuildagent

# check docker group
grep 'docker' /etc/group 

usermod -aG root vstsbuildagent

sudo systemctl restart docker

# your build agent process
sudo systemctl stop vsts******** 
sudo systemctl start vsts********
```