# Docker in Docker | Github actions - Self Hosted Runner

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile, google-kubernetes-engine, github-actions

Am trying to create a self-hosted runner for Github actions on Kubernetes. As a first step was trying with the docker file as below:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

# set the github runner version
ARG RUNNER_VERSION="2.283.1"

# update the base packages and add a non-sudo user
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && useradd -m docker
RUN useradd -r -g docker nonroot
# install python and the packages the your code depends on along with jq so we can parse JSON
# add additional packages as necessary
RUN apt-get install -y curl jq build-essential libssl-dev apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl software-properties-common

# install docker
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | apt-key add - \
    && add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable" \
    && apt update \
    && apt-cache policy docker-ce \
    && apt install docker-ce -y

ENV TINI_VERSION v0.19.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini
RUN usermod -aG docker nonroot
USER nonroot
# set the entrypoint to the start.sh script
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--"]
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

After doing a build, I run the container with the below command:

```
 docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -it srunner
```

When i try to pull image, I get the below error:

```
nonroot@0be0cdccb29b:/$ docker run hello-world
docker: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/create": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
nonroot@0be0cdccb29b:/$
```

Please advise if there is a possible way to run docker as non-root inside a docker container.

Comment: This is on Kubernetes so I'm no sure but I had similar case on VM on Azure DevOps selft hosted agent and [these steps solved the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69162259/2347999)

Comment: It works good for me on Compute Engine ( VM on GCP ) @KrzysztofMadej. But I would like to take it to Kubernetes

Comment: Have you tried this? https://techoverflow.net/2017/03/01/solving-docker-permission-denied-while-trying-to-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-socket/

Comment: Yes, I have tried

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using sockets, there is also a way to connect to outer docker, from docker in container, over TCP.

Linux example:

Run `ifconfig`, it will print the docker's network interface that is created when you install docker on a host node. Its usually named `docker0`, note down the IP address of this interface.

Now, modify the `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and add this`tcp://IP:2375` to the `hosts` section. Restart docker service.

Run containers with extra option: `--add-host=host.docker.internal:host-gateway`

Inside any such container, the address `tcp://host.docker.internal:2375` now points to the outside docker engine.

Comment: Thanks SD, but the plan is to run the same as Kubernetes deployment. In that case it may not be possible to modify the settings on the fly

Answer (score 0):

Try adding your username to the docker group as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue).
Additionally, you should check your kernel [compatibility](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/#kernel-compatibility).

Comment: Will check the same

Comment: @WytrzymałyWiktor Yes, I used DIND container to achieve the same and was able to use Github hosted runners in Kubernetes. Links for your reference.

`https://sanderknape.com/2020/03/self-hosted-github-actions-runner-kubernetes/`

`https://github.com/sokube/github-k8s-runner`

Answer (score 0):

just found this issue that I solved recently.
You need to specify group ID that docker group have on your host, for mounted socket to have permissions.
Example can be found here
https://github.com/HomeLabHQ/runner